# dynamic allocated matrix - how to initialize and set the pointers inside each cell - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, dynamic-memory-allocation, setter

Could someone tell me why my set methods (setHorizontal and setVertical) are not working?

When the set method is finished, I see no change at the matrix.

I dynamically allocated the matrix (which is a member of TrafficSystem class). I think the problem is related to initialization. But when the constructor of cell is called, the class member pointers are supposed to be initialized to `nullptr`.

TrafficSystem.cc:

```cpp
void TrafficSystem::populateMatrix() {

    // create the dynamic allocation of the matrix
    _matrix = new cell * [_n];
    for (int i = 0; i < _n; i++) {
        _matrix[i] = new cell[_m];
    }

    // loop over the streets and insert them to the matrix
    for (int st = 0; st < _allStreets.size(); st++)
    {
        street *current_street = &(_allStreets.at(st));
        int x = current_street->getX();
        int y = current_street->getY();
        int length = (current_street->getStreet_length()) / RATIO;

        if (current_street->getDirection() == street::direction::Horizontal) {
            for (int j = y; j < length; j++) {
               _matrix[x][j].setHorizontal(current_street);
            }
        }
        else if (current_street->getDirection() == street::direction::Vertical) {
            for (int i = x; i < length; i++) {
                _matrix[i][y].setVertical(current_street);
            }
        }
}
```

cell.h:

```cpp
class cell
{
private:
    const street* _horizontalSt;
    const street* _verticalSt;
public:
    cell(street* horizontalSt = nullptr, street* verticalSt = nullptr): _horizontalSt(horizontalSt), _verticalSt(verticalSt){}  
    ~cell() {};
    const street* getSt1() const { return _horizontalSt; }
    const street* getSt2() const { return _verticalSt; }
    void setHorizontal(const street* st) { _horizontalSt = st;}
    void setVertical(const street* st) { _verticalSt = st; }
};
```

Comment: could you add the constructor also? additionally make sure `x` and `y` are within the bounds `_n` and `_m`

Comment: Hi Shir M, why are the two private set fields **const** ? I'm not really familiar with C++ details, but in most languages you can't change a const.. and by the way, all streets go vertical or horizontal in your traffic system. That would not make it a really suitable data model for my city over here in Europe !

Comment: Please make a [mre]. We'll need to see the `TrafficSystem` class as well.

Comment: The constructor is on cell.h : cell(street* horizontalSt = nullptr, street* verticalSt = nullptr): _horizontalSt(horizontalSt), _verticalSt(verticalSt){}

Comment: This class violates the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Consider using a `std::vector` instead of managing your own memory, then destruction, copying, and moving all become automatic. As written, copying and moving result in shared state, possible use-after-free, and guaranteed double-delete.